# MongoDB: E11000 duplicate key error - followed by a find with no records returned

Tags: mongodb

I am having an issue with an insertOne() failing due to "E11000 duplicate key error" but then a subsequent find is not finding the dup. My code traps this specific error, treating it as an expected occurrence, and then performs a find on the same _id. My issue is that the find() does not find any matching records - this is the unexpected part.

Pseudo code (ColdFusion, arrays are base 1):

```
findResponse = variables.daoTokenVaultService.find({ "_id": "mykey" });
if( findResponse.count()==0 ){
    try{
        variables.daoTokenVaultService.insertOne({ "_id": "mykey", "value": "value" });
    } catch( any e ) {
        if( findNoCase("E11000 duplicate key error", e.message) ){
            // key was added since we checked last, simply refind
        } else {
            rethrow;
        }
    }
}
findResponse = variables.daoTokenVaultService.find({ "_id": "mykey" });
if( findResponse.count()==0 ){
    throw("Argh! Key not found, attempted insert, dup detected, key still not found!");
}
return findResponse.toArray()[1];
```

The "argh!" is thrown. I'm relying on the _id being unique. There is a second unique sparse index defined for the collection, but the key value is not assigned in this case so _id should be the only index in play. There is no sharding in play either (at least not that I am aware of - sample mongodb docker instance "image: mongo").

Argh! Help.

Comment: What are your indices? It seems likely you have another index on a different key. I've seen this most commonly with a field that is indexed but set to null, and trying to save another key with the null indexed field failing.

Comment: Thanks @AdamExchange, I went back and checked the index. When I mentioned "sparse" in my OP, that was an implied sparse. I did not realize there was an actual { "unique": true, "sparse": true } setting. Since adding the parameter the issue I was having seems to be resolved.

It's been a while since I have used stackoverflow. Should I repost your comment as the answer, or let you post so you can get credit?